# "android.view.WindowLeaked" error when opening new "StringRequest"

Tags: java, android

First time here :)

I am a complete beginner trying to learn to make android apps, and i have ran into and issue i cannot get around.

I am running the code below, and when it runs the "StringRequest stringRequest" the program errors and does not run the code i expect it to run next.

This is on Android Studio, i have had a look at some of the similar entries online but i have not got anywhere yet... help :)

```
public void save(View v){

    String name = etName.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
    editor.apply();

    getSqlDetails();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReportaFault.class);
    AddCustomerNumber.this.finish();
    startActivity(intent);

}

private void getSqlDetails() {
    String name = etName.getText().toString();

    Log.e("eTName is:", name );

    String url= "https://localhost/ConvertIDtoName.php?id="+name;
    pd.show();

    Log.e("URL is:", url );

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    pd.hide();

                    Log.e("", "Check if it fails after PD" );

                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String fullname = jsonobject.getString("fullname");

                            Log.e("fullname is:", fullname );
                            //result.setText(id + fullname);

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                            editor.putString(KEY_ID, fullname);
                            editor.apply();

                            Log.e("key_id is:", fullname );
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(error != null){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

    );
}
```

```
2019-05-15 19:49:41.845 19997-19997/faultlogforandroid E/eTName is:: testuser
        2019-05-15 19:49:42.205 19997-19997/faultlogforandroid E/URL is:: 
        https://localhost/ConvertIDtoName.php?id=testuser
2019-05-15 19:49:47.310 19997-19997/faultlogforandroid E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity faultlogforandroid.AddCustomerNumber has leaked window DecorView@d7ffc93[AddCustomerNumber] that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:627)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:377)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:342)
        at faultlogforandroid.AddCustomerNumber.getSqlDetails(AddCustomerNumber.java:101)
        at faultlogforandroid.AddCustomerNumber.save(AddCustomerNumber.java:85)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7251)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7228)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:802)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27843)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
```